# How can i retrive a imagem URL from Firebase Storage to a imagemview directly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I retrieve an image that I uploaded on Firebase Storage to an `ImageView`? I already uploaded an `ImageView` from my pc to storage, now I need to retrieve it to an `ImageView` inside my app. How can I do that?

That's how I was trying to do.

```
db.collection("Ads").document("Ads1").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                String titulo = documentSnapshot.getString("titulo");
                String subtitulo = documentSnapshot.getString("subtitulo");
                String imagem1 = documentSnapshot.getString("imagem1");

                textViewAdsTitulo.setText(titulo);
                textViewAdsSub.setText(subtitulo);
                imageView1.setImageURI();//Can't get i as string;
```

Comment: Consider using Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use picasso

First add `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828` in the build.gradle> dependencies

Then use `Picasso.get().load(your_url).into(your_imageView)`

Comment: Have you stored the url on firestore?